# How to Configure AWS API GATEWAY with cognito user pool authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Trying to configure AWS API Gateway with AWS Cognito userpool authentication.
Tried some of the settings provided on aws documentation and trying to check this API from Postman client.

Not able check what setting need to be done at postman side and any specific configuration needs to be done at API and Cognito.

Thanks

Comment: Using postman will be a little tricky since you have to calculate a JWT Token with Cognito and API Gateway. Plus the token has a timeout on it so you have to keep calculating it. You are best off starting with a script that can get you the JWT token and be making API calls from that script.

Comment: I agree with h the above comment, write a script to interact with Cognito and get the JWT token which you can paste into your 'Authorisation' header in postman.

Comment: To test you can use the admin-initiate-auth using aws cli to get the idToken to pass in Postman. This forum has the entire process documented https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=733601.
The other way is to the the Cognito user pools SDK to get the idToken and then pass to api gateway in Authorization header.